# Django : Streaming data with PyPDF2

Tags: django, pypdf

When the pdf is generate , i would like to avoid saving a file to disk :

```
    output_pdf = PdfWriter()

    for i in range(len(input_pdf.pages)):
        page = input_pdf.pages[i]
        if i == 0:
            page.merge_page(text_pdf.pages[0])
        output_pdf.add_page(page)

    with open('assets/media/consignes.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        output_pdf.write(f)
        f.close()

    return FileResponse(open('assets/media/consignes.pdf','rb'), as_attacheement=False, content_type='application/pdf')
```